# How to deal with "Could not broadcast input array from shape (1141,2) into shape (1141,)" to get Out-of-Bag error while using Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, pandas, random-forest, numpy, multilabel-classification

I have a dataset that consists of 171 features and 39 labels. I captured both features and labels of the dataset through slicing:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dir_name + "Labeled Data - New Columns and No Nominal Data.csv")
X = df0.iloc[:, :171]
Y = df0.iloc[:, 171:]
```

Then I checked the shape of my X and Y arrays:

```
X.shape
results to (3103, 171)

Y.shape
results to (3103, 39)
```

Now my problem is that the y-axis of both numpy arrays are clearly unequal, especially since the features and labels differ in value. Whenever I fit them into the Random Forest Model in order to also get the OOB error, it results to **could not broadcast input array from shape (1141,2) into shape (1141,)**. I am aware that I still need to train test split X and Y, but for now, I will not be doing so.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

rf = RandomForestClassifier(oob_score=True, random_state=0)

#OOB SIMPLIFIED
rf.fit(X, Y)
oob_error = 1 - rf.oob_score_

# Print the OOB error
print(f'OOB error: {oob_error:.3f}')

rf = RandomForestClassifier(oob_score=True, random_state=0)
```

I am quite sure that this error occurs because at least one of the items in the list that I am converting to an array doesn't match the dimensions or the other elements. To solve the error, I have to make sure the dimensions of all elements in my list match, in which now I am not sure how to do it. I am torn apart in using transpose() or other functionalities such as numpy.hstack or numpy.zeros to fill in the y-axis.

Pictures of results:

**DF**
[image: DF]

**X**
[image: X]

**Y**
[image: Y]

**Random Forest**
[image: RF]

**Error Result**
[image: Error]

Your responses would indeed help me a lot, and please do excuse me for some of my errors since I am fairly new in Machine Learning and currently exploring the uses of Random Forest.

Thank you very much